# It is possible to express $\frac{x^{2}-9}{x^{2}{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}$ as $\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}$?

Tags: real-numbers, partial-fractions

## Question

The fraction $\dfrac{x^{2}-9}{x^{2}{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}$ can be expressed as $\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}$, where A and B are constants?

### My attempt to solve

I understand as an identity, that is to say:
$$\dfrac{x^{2}-9}{x^{2}{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}=\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}\;\forall x\neq0$$
If $x=3$, then $0=\dfrac{A}{3}+\dfrac{B}{{(3^{2}+9)}^{2}}=\dfrac{A}{3}+\dfrac{B}{18^{2}}\implies 0=6\cdot18\cdot A+B\ldots(\alpha)$

If $x=-3$, then $0=-\dfrac{A}{3}+\dfrac{B}{{({-3}^{2}+9)}^{2}}=-\dfrac{A}{3}+\dfrac{B}{{18}^{2}}\implies 0=A\cdot6\cdot18-B\ldots(\beta)$

Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$: $A=B=0$.

Finally $\dfrac{x^{2}-9}{x^{2}{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}=\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}=\dfrac{0}{x}+\dfrac{0}{{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}=0$

This is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it look correct to you that you find a nontrivial function to be equivalent to the all-0 function?

Comment: No it must be $\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{x^2}+\dfrac{Cx+D}{{(x^{2}+9)}}+\dfrac{Ex+F}{{(x^{2}+9)}^{2}}$

Comment: No, I'm sorry. The question is expressed as the sum of two terms whose denominator are $x$ and $(x^2+9)^2$.

Comment: It is enough to put $\frac{t-9}{t(t+9)^2}$ as partial fractions and replace $t$ by $x^2$. This is $-\frac{1/9}{t}+\frac{2}{(t+9)^2}+\frac{1/9}{t+9}$. Hence the required expression is $-\frac{1/9}{x^2} + \frac{2}{(x^2+9)^2} + \frac{1/9}{x^2+9}$

Comment: Thanks. I'm studying your proof. Could you found A, B constants?

Comment: @Oromion Hola Carlos ;)

Comment: Hola @LuisFelipe, muchos saludos y que estés bien haha, gané 50 puntos!